# Bootstrap navbar-toggleable-sm not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, nav

I'm new to Bootstrap and I'm following a Lynda.com tutorial about the navbar. Unfortunately even though I've done exactly what is in the tutorial, it's not working how it is in the example, and I can't work out what I've done wrong. As far as I'm aware, the navbar links should stack vertically only on md and under, but they seem to be stacking vertically on any size device.

The page is here [www.andycharlton.co.uk](http://www.andycharlton.co.uk)

The specific code is

```
<div class="navmenu">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm">

            <div class="navbar-nav">

                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">One</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Two</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Three</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Four</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Five</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Six</a>

            </div><!--navbar-nav-->    

        </nav><!--nav-->    

    </div><!--navmenu-->
```

Be grateful for any help! Thanks

Comment: did you check the bootstrap [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)?

Comment: Yeah and Ive tried copying and pasting the code directly from the docs and that doesnt work either. I think im loading in jquery and bootstrap.js correctly too so Im stuck for ideas?

Comment: where you see this `navbar-toggleable`  class?

Comment: which version of bootsrap you using?

Comment: 4, you can check the whole html on the link above but I can post it here if that would help?

Comment: you are using `Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.2` and using `Bootstrap  v4-alpha`  code. try the doc from my first comment

Answer (score 13):

Following CSS classes was changed in latest version of Bootstrap 4 including navbar-toggleable-sm:

```
.badge-default to .badge-dark
.bg-faded to .bg-light
.bg-inverse to .bg-dark
.card-block to .card-body
.card-outline-primary to .border-primary
.card-outline-secondary to .border-secondary
.card-outline-success to .border-success
.card-outline-info to .border-info
.card-outline-warning to .border-warning
.card-primary to .bg-primary
.card-success to .bg-success
.card-info to .bg-info
.card-warning to .bg-warning
.card-danger to .bg-danger
.hidden-xs-down to .d-none .d-sm-block
.hidden-sm-down to .d-none .d-md-block
.hidden-md-down to .d-none .d-lg-block
.hidden-lg-down to .d-none .d-xl-block
.hidden-xs-up to .d-none
.hidden-sm-up to .d-sm-none
.hidden-md-up to .d-md-none
.hidden-lg-up to .d-lg-none
.hidden-xl-up to .d-xl-none
.navbar-toggleable-sm to .navbar-expand-sm
.navbar-toggleable-md to .navbar-expand-md
.navbar-toggleable-lg to .navbar-expand-lg
.navbar-toggleable-xl to .navbar-expand-xl
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do in `Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.2`

```
<nav class="nav flex-column flex-sm-row">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">One</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Two</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Three</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Four</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Five</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Six</a>
</nav>
```

this will show menu column like in `md` and above, row like in `sm` devices

Comment: It's still doing the exact same thing for me I'm afraid, I can't see what I've done to make it not work :(

Comment: this works on your live site. i tried. in your case try this `<div class="navbar-nav nav flex-column flex-sm-row">`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I couldn't get it to work still. However I've just started from a template and that's working for me. I think it was to do with whatever css or js files I was loading in. Anyway, thanks for trying